# In pandas, how to display a hist with an additional line graph (or other info on the bins)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe with a column for `age` which I would like to display as a histogram.
That I can easily do using:
`df.age.hist(bins=<bin_num>)`
or
`df.hist('age', bins=<bin_num>)`

However, on the same drawing, I would like to display some info from another column, e.g. average `height` of the data points in that bin.
This could be a line graph (or some other type of graph).
I would also like to be able to easily change the function from average to max/min/mean/etc.

The main problem is I don't really know which values `hist` places in each bin.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the range of the columns may be significantly different; the graph should (probably) look like the ones which have y-axis scales on both sides -- one for each attribute

Comment: `bins` can be a list or array of bin-edges. This allows you to define the binning yourself and use the same bins for any other calculation you might want to perform and eventually display on the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hist graph in Matplotlib returns the BarContainer which contains all the properties of the barplot. You can iterate over each bar and get the 'x' values and height of each bar.

```
df_age  = pd.DataFrame({'AGE': np.random.randint(1,100,200) })
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
plt.hist(df_age['AGE'])
bar_height = []
bar_x = []
bar_x_lst = []
bar_y_lst = []

for bar in ax.patches:
    bar_x.append(bar.get_x())
    bar_height.append(bar.get_height())

for i,val in enumerate(bar_x):
    if i==0:
        bar_x_lst.append(val)
        continue
    bar_x_lst+=[val-0.1,val]

for i,val in enumerate(bar_height):
    if i ==len(bar_height)-1:
        bar_y_lst.append(val)
        continue
    bar_y_lst += [val,val]
bar_x_lst.append(bar_x_lst[-1]+bar.get_width())
bar_y_lst.append(bar_y_lst[-1])
bar_y_lst = [i/2 for i in bar_y_lst]
plt.plot(bar_x_lst,bar_y_lst , c= 'red' )
```

That would return something like this:
[image: Bar_plot]